# read text delimited file and write to excel in matlab

Tags: matlab, text, textscan

I have a txt file in this format:
`Right,28772.163,39356.163,1,Speaker1
sp,39356.163,49499.163,99,Speaker1
sp,129129.21,147210.21,99,Speaker2
Next step is,147210.21,160881.21,1,Speaker2
surgery's,160881.21,181608.21,1,Speaker2`

and it goes on (it has 1016 rows). I would like to convert it into excel file. I tried the following

```
fileID = fopen('test_datum.txt');
C = textscan(fileID,'%s %f32 %f32 %d8 %s');
```

But it inserts the data into a 1016X5 cell. I would like later to write this cell into an excel file.
thank you

Comment: What are you asking? Why can't you write the cell array to an excel file?

Comment: Why are you using Matlab? Such a simple file can be read by excel itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textscan` function can sometimes be tricky to deal with. The data format is hard to define and it tends to cram data into a cell vector (reordering the result into a single cell matrix is kinda annoying). What I suggest you is to use the [readtable function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html) instead:

```
T = readtable('data.txt')


     Var1           Var2         Var3       Var4       Var5   
______________    _________    _________    ____    __________

'Right'           28772.163    39356.163     1      'Speaker1'
'sp'              39356.163    49499.163    99      'Speaker1'
'sp'              129129.21    147210.21    99      'Speaker2'
'Next step is'    147210.21    160881.21     1      'Speaker2'
'surgery's'       160881.21    181608.21     1      'Speaker2'
```

If you have a Matlab release greater than or equal to `R2016b`, you can previously run the [detectImportOptions function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/detectimportoptions.html) on the file. The result of the scan can be tweaked according to your needs (you can change the variable names, variable types, default for missing values, etc...):

```
opts = detectImportOptions('data.txt');

% the previous values where char, double, double, double, char
opts.VariableTypes = {'char' 'single' 'single' 'int8' 'char'};
% alternatively, this can be used:
% opts = setvartype(opts,{'char' 'single' 'single' 'int8' 'char'})

T = readtable('data.txt',opts)


     Var1           Var2        Var3      Var4       Var5   
______________    ________    ________    ____    __________

'Right'           28772.16    39356.16     1      'Speaker1'
'sp'              39356.16    49499.16    99      'Speaker1'
'sp'              129129.2    147210.2    99      'Speaker2'
'Next step is'    147210.2    160881.2     1      'Speaker2'
'surgery's'       160881.2    181608.2     1      'Speaker2'
```

On the top of that, tables are really easy to export to Excel files. All you have to do is to use the [writetable function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html) with the appropriate settings.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate, easier approach that lets MATLAB functions automatically take care of more of the data processing:

```
% read the file into a table
T = readtable('test_datum.txt');

% convert the table to a cell array
C = table2cell(T);

% write the cell array to an Excel file
xlswrite('output.xlsx', C);
```